# What are the typical forcings to shoot a club through a stationary subset of $[\lambda]^\omega$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\lambda\geq \omega_2$ be a regular cardinal and $S\subset[\lambda]^\omega$ be a stationary set. I'm looking for a property of $S$, say "shootable", such that there exists a forcing extension preserving $\lambda, \omega_1$ as cardinals that shoots a club into $S$. I've encountered ad hoc examples, but I'd really hope if there are more explicit descriptions of a stationary set being "shootable" and given that a canonically defined reasonable forcing to shoot a club through it. I'm flexible with any cardinal arithmetic assumptions.

Comment: Have you seen examples that do not satisfy the definition of "fat" given below?

Comment: @MonroeEskew any non-reflecting stationary subset of $[\omega_2]^\omega$ is not fat.

Comment: I mean examples of shootable sets.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Usuba's "Reflection principles for $\omega_2$ and the semistationary reflection principle" has another example, ultimately derived from some ideas of Sakai and Krueger.  He shows that if there is a "nonreflecting ladder system" $\vec{d}$ for $\omega_2 \cap \text{cof}(\omega)$ and $S$ is a nonreflecting stationary set of $x \in [\omega_2]^\omega$ such that $d_{\text{sup}(x)} \subset x$, there is a way to kill stationarity of $S$ while preserving $\omega_1$.  If CH holds then $\omega_2$ is also preserved.

Comment: Is it clear that the complement of $S$ does not satisfy the definition of "fat"?

Comment: @JingZhang I don't know.  However Usuba's forcing to deal with those kinds of stationary sets can be iterated (using countable support iteration, essentially; also the nonreflecting ladder sequence is upward absolute to the relevant forcing extensions).   I don't believe that adding clubs through fat stationary sets can, in general, be iterated (though I'm not certain about that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a notion of fat stationary subset of $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ and a natural forcing for shooting a club through it, that you can find in the thesis [Fat subsets of $P_{\kappa}(\lambda)$](https://open.bu.edu/bitstream/handle/2144/14099/Zaigralin_bu_0017E_10097.pdf?sequence=1) by Ivan Zaigralin. In particular look at chapter 2 of the thesis.

Comment: I noticed that the thesis uses the Jech definition for clubs, and while this is fine for the case in question ($\kappa=\omega$), I seem to recall that this is weaker than the algebraic definition in general.